# AWS cognito login set AuthFlow to USER_PASSWORD_AUTH in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-ios

I’m using *AWS Cognito to perform login authentication*. When login is successful we get below request body :

*Request body:*

```
> {"UserContextData":{"EncodedData":"eyJ..9”},”ClientMetadata":{"cognito:deviceName":"MacBookPro12-01","cognito:bundleShortV":"1.0.0",
> "cognito:idForVendor":"A6FD46FBB205","cognito:bundleVersion":"207",
>     "cognito:bundleId":"com.abc.Project-Dev","cognito:model":"iPhone", "cognito:systemName":"iOS","cognito:iOSVersion":"11.3"},
>     "AuthParameters":{"SRP_A":"a6..627","SECRET_HASH":"vr..Oo=", "USERNAME":"jay.dubey@abc.com”},**”AuthFlow":"USER_SRP_AUTH"**,
> "ClientId”:”123”}
```

Now, there is a scenario wherein I’ve to **set “AuthFlow” value to “USER_PASSWORD_AUTH”.** How can this be done?

The headache with this is that **all these values are set in Pods.** Below code prints the request body that is added above :

```
passwordAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails(username: username, password: password))
```

Comment: Have you looked at AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAuthFlowTypeUserPasswordAuth? See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/a50e487cc71fc9345bdd55b8bdfe0eb08c7250ac/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityUser.m#L616

Comment: @Karthikeyan : I had gone through mentioned link earlier. I think this may help but no idea how to call?

Answer (score 3):

If you will look into AWSCognitoIdentityUser in method getSessionWithUserName andPassword you will see that there is a ternary operator switching migration auth that is driven by migrationEnabled Boolean value. In order to switch auth type just configure identity pool like so:

```
  let userPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration (
        clientId: clientId,
        clientSecret: nil,
        poolId: userPoolId,
        shouldProvideCognitoValidationData: false,
        pinpointAppId: nil,
        migrationEnabled: true
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

I found you need to enable the migration in your `amplifyconfigurqaton.json` so that it uses the `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` mode (it will ignore it otherwise):

```
{
    "auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "CredentialsProvider": {
                    "CognitoIdentity": {
                        "Default": {
                            "PoolId": "xxxx",
                            "Region": "xxxxx"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": "xxxxx",
                        "AppClientId": "xxxxx",
                        "Region": "xxxxx",
                        "MigrationEnabled" : true
                    }
```